# MQTT messages opening too many TCP connections on Websockets in React

Tags: reactjs, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto, micropython

I have a ESP32 device sending data at a very fast rate using `umqtt` module. Also, a `Mosquitto` broker listening on ports 1883 for `mqtt` and 9001 for `websockets`. Finally, a react App showing messages in real-time.

The problem is that every time the React App receives a message from the ESP device, a new `TCP` connection is established, resulting in a lot of opened connections, as you can see here:

```
pi@rthree:/etc/mosquitto $ ss -s
Total: 449
TCP:   334 (estab 257, closed 70, orphaned 0, timewait 68)

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
RAW   1         0         1        
UDP   6         3         3        
TCP   264       261       3        
INET      271       264       7        
FRAG      0         0         0
```

How can I solve this overload of connections?

Any recommendations?

In the front-end, this is the React App:

```
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import './App.css';
import mqtt from "mqtt";

function App() {
const [mess, setMess] = useState("0")

const options = {"username":"user","password":"password"}
const client = mqtt.connect("ws://192.168.1.166:9001",options);
client.subscribe("temp_orientation");

const update_mqtt = () =>{
    client.on("message", function (topic, message) {
      const mssg = message.toString();
      setMess(mssg);
         
    } )
}
useEffect(()=>{
    update_mqtt();
},[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">

      <h1>Data: {mess}</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is the backend:

```
import mpu6050
from machine import SoftI2C, Pin, PWM, ADC, reset
from time import sleep
import network
import wifi
import math

from umqtt import robust as mqtt

try:
    wifi.wifi_connect()
except:
    wifi.hotspot_connect()

mqtt_server = "192.168.1.166"
client_id = "usero"
topic_sub = 'temp_orientation'

def sub_cb(topic, msg):
  print(topic, msg)


def connect_and_subscribe():
  global client_id, mqtt_server, topic_sub
  client = mqtt.MQTTClient(client_id, mqtt_server,user='user00001', password='password')
  client.set_callback(sub_cb)
  client.connect()
  client.subscribe(topic_sub)
  return client

def restart_and_reconnect():
  print('Failed to connect to MQTT broker. Reconnecting...')
  sleep(1)
  reset()

try:
  client = connect_and_subscribe()
except OSError as e:
  restart_and_reconnect()

# mpu sensor

i2c = SoftI2C(scl=Pin(22),sda=Pin(21))
a = mpu6050.accel(i2c)

tprev = 0
mprev = False
m = 0

while True:
    
    values = a.get_values()
    z = values["AcZ"]
    t = math.floor(int(values["Tmp"]) * 10) / 10
    
    if int(z) < 0:
        m = "DOWN"
        
    if int(z) > 0:
        m = "UP"
     
    if t != tprev or m != mprev:
        mprev = m
        tprev = t
        try:
            client.check_msg()
            client.publish("temp_orientation", "{} {}".format(str(t),m))
        
        except OSError as e:
            restart_and_reconnect()
                      
    sleep(0.2)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Side comment:  Most environments don't change temperature as fast as 200ms!!  I usually set my temp reading sensors to send every 5 minutes and that works just fine.  Its no wonder you are swamping part of your system with MQTT messages.

Comment: @JDAllen I am not only sending temperature data, I am also sending mpu6050 orientation data, which can change very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved after moving all the mqtt logic constants into the useEffect. Now it updates the state after every received message and does not keep the connection open.

```
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import './App.css';
import mqtt from "mqtt";

function App() {
const [mess, setMess] = useState("0")

useEffect(()=>{
    const options = {"username":"user","password":"password"}
    const client = mqtt.connect("ws://192.168.1.166:9001",options);
    client.subscribe("temp_orientation");
    const update_mqtt = () =>{
        client.on("message", function (topic, message) {
            const mssg = message.toString();
            setMess(mssg);
         } )
}
    update_mqtt();
},[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">

      <h1>Data: {mess}</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```